# Assigning figure size to a figure with a given handle (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, figures

is there a way to assign the outerposition property of a figure to a figure with a given handle?

For example, if I wanted to define a figure as say figure 1, I would use:

```
 figure(1)
 imagesc(Arrayname) % I.e. any array
```

I can also change the properties of a figure using the code:

```
figure('Name', 'Name of figure','NumberTitle','off','OuterPosition',[scrsz(1) scrsz(2) 700 700]);
```

Is there a propertyname I can use to assign the outerposition property to the figure assigned as figure 1?

The reason I am asking this is because I am using a command called save2word (from the MATLAB file exchange) to save some plots from a function I have made to a word file, and I want to limit the number of figures I have open as it does this.

The rest of the code I have is:

```
plottedloops = [1, 5:5:100]; % Specifies which loops I want to save


GetGeometry = getappdata(0, 'GeometryAtEachLoop') % Obtains a 4D array containing geometry information at each loop


NumSections = size(GetGeometry,4); %Defined by the fourth dimension of the 4D array

for j = 1:NumSections
    for  i = 1:plottedloops
    P = GetGeometry(:,:,i,j);

    TitleSize = 14;
    Fsize = 8;
    % Save Geometry

    scrsz = get(0,'ScreenSize'); %left, bottom, width height   


  figure('Name', 'Geometry at each loop','NumberTitle','off','OuterPosition',[scrsz(1) scrsz(2) 700 700]); This specifies the figure name, dims etc., but also means multiple figures are opened as the command runs.

% I have tried this, but it doesn't work:
% figure(0, 'OuterPosition',[scrsz(1) scrsz(2) 700 700]);

    imagesc(P), title('Geometry','FontSize', TitleSize), axis([0 100 0 100]);

    text(20,110,['Loop:',num2str(i)], 'FontSize', TitleSize); % Show loop in figure
    text(70,110,['Section:',num2str(j)], 'FontSize', TitleSize);% Show Section number in figure

    save2word('Geometry at each loop'); % Saves figure to a word file

end
```

end

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you capture the figure handle when you create the figure

```
figH = figure;
```

You can assign properties any time you want

```
set(figH,'OuterPosition',[scrsz(1),scrsz(2),700,700]);
```

You can also gather the figure handles inside a vector, and then set all sizes at once.

If you cannot capture the figure handle for some reason, you can use `findall` to look for a figure with a specific name, or `gcf` to get the handle of the current (last selected/opened) figure.

Comment: What's frustrating about this is that it appears to be impossible to create a figure with a specific handle and properties that is not visible. I often create a figure with 'Visible' set to 'off', then create the figure's contents, and then make it visible once it is ready. The fact that you can't both set a figure's handle and it's visibility without first creating a visible figure has led me down the path of many an inelegant work-around.

Comment: @EddyTheB: why would you want to set a specific handle? Maybe there's something I'm not seeing, but setting the `tag` property usually does the trick for me, so that I can even have "hidden" handles but am still able to specifically access the figure via `figH = findall(0,'tag','mySpecificFigureHandle')`

Comment: I have class that raises a figure, and one of the properties of the class is the handle for the figure. So say I call the class and it creates a figure with handle '2', but then I close the figure and open some other figure, that new figure will have handle '2'. And the handle in the original figure is pointing at an inappropriate figure.

Comment: Certainly not an issue for most people and yes there are plenty ways around it, it just seems strange to me that I can open a figure with a specific handle, or I can open a figure with specific properties, but I can't do both.

Comment: @EddyTheB: That's why you want to set `handleVisibility` to `false`, and address figures by tag only. The property holding the figure handle would be a dependent property with a get method that (1) checks whether the existing handle (stored in a hidden property) is stale, and (2) raises a new figure if yes.

Comment: Yes, that does sound like a better way of doing it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions/corrections:

- Your second for loop should look like this:

  ```
  for i = plottedloops
  ```

  This is because `plottedloops` is *already* an array, and you want `i` to take on each sequential value in the array for each pass through the loop. For example, a common form for a [for loop](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/for.html) is:

  ```
  for i = 1:someScalarValue
  ```

  Where the term `1:someScalarValue` *creates* an array for you.
- It looks like you are wanting to plot something in a figure window, then save it with `save2word`, then plot something else, then save that, etc. Therefore, I suggest creating your figure window *outside* your for loops, and simply replotting the window contents within the loop. If you move these two lines outside your loops:

  ```
  scrsz = get(0,'ScreenSize'); %left, bottom, width height   
  figure('Name', 'Geometry at each loop','NumberTitle','off',...
         'OuterPosition',[scrsz(1) scrsz(2) 700 700]);
  ```

  Then you should only have one figure at a time open.